# Find nearest Color from a colors list

Tags: android

I have a list of colors with R,G,B values. Some of data is shown below using "Color.rgb(R,G,B)". 
Then I have image processing, when user touches somewhere on an image, I get an RGB value for that touched pixel. How do I search this RGB value from my colors list. 
    Search function should be:if RGB exists in list return position or value. If RGB does not exist, return nearest value from list. 
My search function to is:

```
List<Colors> colors;
touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
            Colors color=colors.get(i);
            if (touchedRGB==Color.rgb(color.getRcolor(),color.getGcolor(), color.getBcolor())) {
                Log.v("OK", "Color found at:"+i);
            }
        }
```

it only checks and returns if color exists not closest one.
Here is code for list of colors:

```
    public class Colors {

public int rowid;
public int Rcolor;
public int Gcolor;
public int Bcolor;
public int RGB;
public int getRowid() {
    return rowid;
}

public void setRowid(int rowid) {
    this.rowid = rowid;
}
public int getRcolor() {
    return Rcolor;
}

public void setRcolor(int Rcolor) {
    this.Rcolor = Rcolor;
}

public int getGcolor() {
    return Gcolor;
}

public void setGcolor(int Gcolor) {
    this.Gcolor = Gcolor;
}

public int getBcolor() {
    return Bcolor;
}

public void setBcolor(int Bcolor) {
    this.Bcolor = Bcolor;
}

}
```

**Log Cat:**

```
06-02 04:40:59.911: V/Color(1539): RGB:-2064 R:255 G:247 B:240
06-02 04:40:59.921: V/Color(1539): RGB:-139303 R:253 G:223 B:217
06-02 04:40:59.981: V/Color(1539): RGB:-147017 R:253 G:193 B:183
06-02 04:41:00.031: V/Color(1539): RGB:-352102 R:250 G:160 B:154
06-02 04:41:00.121: V/Color(1539): RGB:-555139 R:247 G:135 B:125
06-02 04:41:00.171: V/Color(1539): RGB:-2136478 R:223 G:102 B:98
06-02 04:41:00.181: V/Color(1539): RGB:-3781045 R:198 G:78 B:75
06-02 04:41:00.221: V/Color(1539): RGB:-197923 R:252 G:250 B:221
06-02 04:41:00.361: V/Color(1539): RGB:-3403 R:255 G:242 B:181
```

Comment: And what have you tried ? Cause your code is quite useless to us as such...

Comment: I tried to check if the color exists,that worked well,not for closest color in list.

Comment: I think you must build a color lookup table and then assign values like "similar to" #ffeedd, or such - you might get multiple responses - because you might classify a color as similar to red and also to yellow. You will have to enter over 16 mln color data, though.

Comment: I meant "show us what you've tried" , meaning the code. I won't be able to help you anyway but if anyone can, it would be easier for him to start from existing code and identify the problem. Also, SO is not about "code this for me", so you need to show some efforts. As Der Golem suggestes, the first issue would be to know the exact expected result as a color can be close to many others that would be in your array.

Comment: A different approach would be to make a learning system: no match found, you enter the value. So you save yourself to enter 16+ mln data at once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a "distance" function that compares 2 colors and gives you the distance.  Equal colors will have a distance of 0.

There are many ways to implement the distance, based on what "closest color" means to you.  The simplest would be to just use the sum of the RGB differences:

```
public int Distance(Color a, Color b) {
    return Math.Abs(a.r - b.r) + Math.Abs(a.g - b.g) + Math.Abs(a.b - b.b);
}
```

Or you could interpret RGB as a point in 3D space and get the geometric distance, which would look something like this:

```
public double Distance(Color a, Color b) {
    return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a.r - b.r, 2) + Math.Pow(a.g - b.g, 2) + Math.Pow(a.b - b.b, 2));
}
```

This is usually good enough for most simple applications.  If you want a more realistic comparison, you would probably translate the RGB color to something like HSV and compare mostly based on hue.

Comment: Brilliant answer, many thanks. One question though; shouldn't the blue calculations above be (a.b - b.b) rather than (a.b - b.g)?

Comment: @biddster  Hahahaha oops.  That's why you shouldn't copy+paste!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can we do the same using `hsb` colors??

Comment: @viper, yes although in practice you might find it more practical to give a higher weight to the Hue

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
   int redValue = Color.red(touchedRGB);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(touchedRGB);
    int greenValue = Color.green(touchedRGB);
    System.out.println("<<<<<>>>>>>>"+"R:" + redValue + "G:" + greenValue + "B:"    + blueValue);
```